# How to get original value of encrypted cookies in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, encryption, cookies

I am try to get the value of encrypted cookies but not getting the original value.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['email'])):

    Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('email', $uid, time() + (86400 * 30)));          

endif;
```

The cookies are set properly but the cookies are in encrypted format. how to get its original value.

I retrieve cookies like this "Cookie::get('email');"

but it is in encrypted format.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on a dev project, you can disable cookie encryption by modifying the kernel.php file (app/Http/Kernel.php) for web.  In the "$middlewareGroups" array, comment out the EncryptCookiess::class line

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,

    ],
```

Comment it out to look like:

```
 /**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        //\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,

    ],
```

In a production environment, you should use encrypted cookies. You can decrypt them using something along the lines of:

`\Crypt::decrypt(\Request::cookie(config('session.cookie')))`